# Как работают все Layout'ы в Python Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

Сколько смотрю официальную документацию Kivy, так и не могу понять до конца за что отвечает каждый Layout. Немного понимаю только Grid, Box и Anchor, а вот остальные вообще не понимаю, в интернете не могу найти каких нибудь гайдов для чайников.
Если такие есть то оставьте ссылку пожалуйста, понимаю очень тупой вопрос, но мне больше негде спросить. Надеюсь на понимание.

Не могу дать позицию для `TextInput`, пробовал через `AnchorLayout` но увы либо оно сверху, либо оно на весь экран если `Size_hint` выставить на 1,1. Пробовал с другими Layout'ами играться, бесполезно.

Comment: Новички обычно изучают старый и древнейший Tk, либо PyQT в качестве GUI. Про Kivy я не нашел какой-либо хорошей информации. Даже на озоне одна тоненькая книга и та на английском. Поэтому без опыта с GUI пытаться вникнуть сразу в Kivy достаточно сложно.

Comment: Я не работал с Kivy, но насколько я понял, то size_hint отвечает за размер элемента в процентах от 0 до 1. К примеру size_hint_x = 0.5 отразит элемент в 50% от занимаемой площади по горизонтали (горизонталь т.к. _x). Если size_hint включить в None, то тогда можно указывать через width и height размеры. А в остальном вроде документация Kivy наглядно показывает, что происходит с элементом. Опять же, я считаю, что тут проходит граница, где заканчиваются гайды для чайников. Из альтернативных источников я предпочитаю книги, вместо тотуриалов, они дают более полную информацию - но не всем заходит.

Comment: Хотя, мне честно понравился язык описания интерфейсом Kivy Language в нем, который я мельком заметил. Можно еще порыться на хабре и поискать там статейки.

Comment: Это хорошо, но вот у Kivy есть одна запарка, он очень вредный в отличии от других фреймворков. Особенно с этими координатами, нет чтобы старые добрые пиксели оставить, они свои проценты пихают которые фиг поймешь как расположены. Ну попробую еще сегодня эти поля сделать, а так если не смогу, то придется на другой фреймворк переучиваться.:\

Comment: Онлайн чат Kivy (russian) - https://discord.gg/Qe4XawP 
Онлайн чат Kivy (english)- https://discord.gg/csgWFhx 
Онлайн чат KivyMD - https://discord.gg/59vzaF4

Comment: Для пикселей используйте FloatLayout и будет вам счастье. RelativeLayout тоже что и флоат, только он создаёт собственную локальную систему координат (все виджеты будут строиться внутреннего и относительно него), как он работает пока не практиковался, но в планах с ним поработать есть желание.

Comment: Через Float не работает, хз почему, всячески через него пробовал, строка остается снизу, иногда чуть перемещается

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот как я снимал стресс)))
Возможно не все правильно и грамотно, но ... Работает.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

import random

#В этом приложении будет несколько экранов
#на каждом из экранов будет свой способ позиционирования элементов

#Загружаю разметку
Builder.load_string('''
<Main>:
    BoxLayout:
        padding:10
        orientation:'vertical'
        Button:
            text:'next screen'
            on_press:root.manager.current='second'
        Label:
            text:'This is RelativeLayout'
        ScrollView:
            size_hint_y:None
            height:root.height*0.8
            RelativeLayout:
                id:my_box
                size_hint_y:None
                height:1216

<Second>:
    BoxLayout:
        padding:10
        orientation:'vertical'
        Button:
            text:'next screen'
            on_release:root.manager.current='third'
            size_hint:(1,0.1)
        Label:
            text:'This is BoxLayout'
            size_hint:(1,0.2)
        BoxLayout:
            spacing:10
            orientation:'vertical'
            BoxLayout:
                Label:
                    text:'left top'
                Label:
                    text:'right top'
            BoxLayout:
                Label:
                    text:'left bottom'
                Label:
                    text:'right bottom'


<Third>:
    FloatLayout:
        BoxLayout:
            orientation:'vertical'
            size_hint:None,None
            size:(root.my_width-50,root.my_height*0.2)
            pos:(25,root.my_height*0.6)
            Button:
                text:'next screen'
                on_press:root.manager.current='fourth'
            Label:
                text:'This is FloatLayout'
        BoxLayout:
            id:my_box
            size_hint:None,None
            height:50
            width:70
            pos:(root.my_width/3,root.my_height/3)
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba:(1,1,0,1)
                Rectangle:
                    pos:my_box.pos
                    size:(my_box.width,my_box.height)
        BoxLayout:
            id:my_box1
            size_hint:None,None
            height:100
            width:30
            pos:(120,130)
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba:(1,0,0,1)
                Rectangle:
                    pos:my_box1.pos
                    size:(my_box1.width,my_box1.height)
        Label:
            text:'I just some label'
            size_hint:None,None
            width:200
            height:50
            pos:(20,70)

<Fourth>:
    GridLayout:
        cols:3
        id:this_layout

''')

class Main(Screen):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        #В этом классе я впервые использую RelativeLayout
        #Есть некоторые нюансы - нужно заранее знать конечный размер лейаута
        #а иногда это не всегда будет получаться
        #я взял грубо 1216 пикселей(вручную посчитал), ведь для ScrollView нужно указывать размер виджета, который в него вложен, иначе он его не будет прокручивать
        #в будущем подумаю, как можно сделать это динамически
        self.flag=True#с помощью этого бросаю виджеты то в левую колонку, то в правую
        posess_y1=1216#максимальная высота левой колонки
        posess_y2=1216#то же, только правой
        for i in range(16):#случайным образом выставляю высоту виджета(кнопки)
            num=random.choice((0,1))
            if num==1:
                my_height=150
            else:
                my_height=100
            if self.flag:#значит кидаем виджет в левую колонку
                posess_y1-=(my_height+2)#нужно помнить, что в kivy рисование происходит с левого нижнего угла, координаты которого 0 и 0
                #значит нужно отступить от верхней границы на выстоту кнопки с отступом в 2 пикселя

                #перед тем как задать позицию и размер виджета нужно дать ему size_hint=(None,None), а потом вручную задать позицию и размер, с необходимыми отступами
                self.ids.my_box.add_widget(Button(text=str(i+1),size_hint=(None,None),height=my_height,width=(Window.width/2)-10,pos=(0,posess_y1)))
                self.flag=False
            else:
                posess_y2-=(my_height+2)
                self.ids.my_box.add_widget(Button(text=str(i+1),size_hint=(None,None),height=my_height,width=(Window.width/2)-10,pos=(Window.width/2,posess_y2)))
                self.flag=True

class Second(Screen):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)


class Third(Screen):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        #эти размеры нужны для того чтобы виджет не выходил за пределы экрана
        #создаю обязательно до super, иначе у меня не работает
        #в разметке всем виджетам задаю size_hint:None,None
        #а потом размещаю как мне нужно с заданными размерами
        self.my_height=Window.height
        self.my_width=Window.width
        super().__init__(**kwargs)


class Fourth(Screen):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.list_buttons=[
            '7','8','9',
            '4','5','6',
            '1','2','3',
            'None','0','None',
            ]
        for i in self.list_buttons:
            self.ids.this_layout.add_widget(Button(text=i,on_press=self.pressing))

    def pressing(self,instance):
        print(instance.text)
        self.manager.current='first'


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        sm=ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(Main(name='first'))
        sm.add_widget(Second(name='second'))
        sm.add_widget(Third(name='third'))
        sm.add_widget(Fourth(name='fourth'))
        return sm


if __name__=="__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

Comment: С другими пока не игрался, ничего о них пока не могу сказать. То, что использовал покрывает пока все мои идеи.

Comment: Вот это чувак ты дал жару) Щас попробую строку ввода через Float еще раз изменить

Comment: Каким то чудом я сделал это, правда все равно не так как хотел. Ну да ладно. Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 1):

AnchorLayout - дочерние элементы привязываются к сторонам этого лэйаута
BoxLayout - дочерние элементы набрасываются один за другим вдоль одной оси, занимая по умолчанию всю область
GridLayout - дочерние элементы добавляются в сетку
FloatLayout - дочерним элементам можно задавать произвольное расположение в системе координат относительно окна девайса
RelativeLayout - дочерним элементам можно давать произвольное расположение в системе координат относительно этого лэйаута

Там ещё есть какие-то, но хватит этого, м?