# Kivy python screenmanger

Tags: python, kivy

Новичок в изучении  Kivy  и не могу понять как реализовать переход screenmanager. Я создаю приложении для тестов, хочу чтобы при ответе на первый вопрос происходил переход на второй. Я не могу понять как реализовать переход с условием, то есть если написали ответ верно в поле textinput, по нажатие кнопки переход на следующий вопрос.

Код не могу предоставить, так как и нет особо.

Answer (score 0):

Для вашей ситуации, полагаю, не нужен скринменеджер, лучше сделать обновление экрана через удаление виджетов и добавлением новых. Вот здесь [Как работают все Layout'ы в Python Kivy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/971899/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5-layout%d1%8b-%d0%b2-python-kivy/972365?noredirect=1#comment1632722_972365) можно посмотреть некоторые способы работы с этим.

Answer (score 0):

Вот простой пример реализации ScreenManager:

**main.py**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget


class Root(Widget):
    pass


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Root()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

**my.kv**

```
<Root>
    BoxLayout:
        size: root.width, root.height

        ScreenManager:
            id: my_screen_manager

            Screen:
                name: 'first_screen'

                BoxLayout:

                    Label:
                        text: "The first screen"

                    Button:
                        text: "Go to screen 2"
                        on_press:
                            my_screen_manager.current = 'second_screen'

            Screen:
                name: 'second_screen'

                BoxLayout:

                    Label:
                        text: "The second screen"

                    Button:
                        text: "Go to screen 1"
                        on_press:
                            my_screen_manager.current = 'first_screen'
```

Либо можно сделать это через код:

**main.py**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty


class Root(Widget):

    my_screen_manager = ObjectProperty(None)
    
    def ChangeMyScreen(self, screen_name):
        self.my_screen_manager.current = str(screen_name)


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Root()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

**my.kv**

```
<Root>

    my_screen_manager: my_screen_manager

    BoxLayout:
        size: root.width, root.height

        ScreenManager:
            id: my_screen_manager

            Screen:
                name: 'first_screen'

                BoxLayout:

                    Label:
                        text: "The first screen"

                    Button:
                        text: "Go to screen 2"
                        on_press:
                            root.ChangeMyScreen('second_screen')

            Screen:
                name: 'second_screen'

                BoxLayout:

                    Label:
                        text: "The second screen"

                    Button:
                        text: "Go to screen 1"
                        on_press:
                            root.ChangeMyScreen('first_screen')
```